# What does it mean: "your focus determinates..."?

Tags: phrases

I've a problem with understanding following "quote" :

> your focus determines your reality

[image]

How does "focus" can determinate something ? May it be about focus of view or something like this ? Can somebody explain it please ?

Comment: It could be rephrased as *"Your perception of reality is determined by the things which you choose to focus on."*

Comment: I think, I get it. "the reality is all the things you're focus on" , right ?

Comment: What is *determinate* supposed to mean?  It has meant *determine* since Shakespeare.

Comment: If you really are interpreting that to mean "determinate" then that's part of your problem.  "Determinate" is not typically used outside of mathematics & science, and it has a different meaning from "determine".

Comment: @HotLicks, I interpret it in the mathematics way too, you're right.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found answer in the dictionary:

> 9. (often foll by: on) to fix attention (on); concentrate

Therefore:

> Your "fixed attention on" determi....

Sounds entirely clean for me.

Answer (score 0):

It means that what you choose to give your attention to, attracts what shows up in your life.

For example, if a person with only one leg focuses on how awful that is, how powerless and sad they feel, then they may spend their life feeling unhappy, as a cripple in a wheelchair. Their condition is unlikely to improve.

However if that same person focused on how grateful they were for their good leg and otherwise healthy body, they might get a replacement leg and become an athlete in the disabled olympic games.  Their condition improves.

The concept being described is known as The Law of Attraction, by the way, if you want to look it up:

'In the New Thought philosophy, the law of attraction is the belief that by focusing on positive or negative thoughts a person brings positive or negative experiences into their life.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_attraction_(New_Thought)

Comment: By the way, in your question you use 'determinates'. This is not a word - 'determines' is the word to use 'your focus determines your reality'.